# Changing pixels of Win32 window

Tags: c, windows, bitmap, pixel

I know that this may be common knowledge, but is there a way to edit RGB values of pixels of Windows window from `C`/`C++` without using libraries like `OpenGL` or `DirectX`? If there is, what are the built-in functions to manipulate pixel buffer directly?

Comment: Check out [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Doing this makes little sense.  Whatever you modify can be wiped out at any time when a window redraws itself.  Reading is useful (screen shot), writing is not.

Comment: @Hans True enough if the window is in a different process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213.aspx) handler you can call [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145078%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).